# Hi, roscore won't start

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Roscore (and some launch files) won't start. The command line stays as it is until I hit Ctrl-C.

I read a separate forum that said something could be wrong with `etc/hosts` , `ROS_IP`, or `ROS_HOSTNAME`  in the `.bashrc`. I think this is the case because I needed to edit my `.bashrc` earlier in order to connect with and control a robot. However, now it seems roscore won't start on the PC.

If you see what the problem is, or have a different idea as to the cause, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Here's my .bashrc:

```
    enter code here# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\\\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\\\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
export EDITOR='nano -w'
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.101.151.20
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://155.33.199.23:11311
```

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266970/hi,-roscore-won%27t-start/) by [rg10](https://answers.ros.org/users/31293/rg10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-09**:
Why did you delete the question? Didn't @SL Remy answer it?

**Comment by [RoboTBiLL](https://answers.ros.org/users/77403/robotbill/) on 2022-06-30**:
How did you solve it?
I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may be significant that your ros_master_uri is different from your ros_hostname.. the ros_master_uri is saying where the roscore is actually running. So there are couple of questions, are you trying to run roscore remotely? Is your IP address 10.101.151.20?

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rg10](https://answers.ros.org/users/31293/rg10/) on 2017-08-02**:
You were right, the problem was that my ros_master_uri was different from my ros_hostname. I had switched from using roscore on a separate machine through my computer to on my computer. It's working well now. Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-02**:
@ronangunning100: if you feel @SL Remy's answer has answered your question, could you please tick the checkmark to the left of his answer? That will clearly mark the question as answered.

Thanks.

**Comment by [rg10](https://answers.ros.org/users/31293/rg10/) on 2017-08-07**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn for the reminder